# Vimeo's JS API: player.loadVideo() method resets player options to its defaults

Tags: javascript, video, vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

I'm using [Vimeo's player.js API](https://github.com/vimeo/player.js), where it states that you can set options on the player, such as `title: false` when initiating the Player object as follows:

```
var options = {
    id: 59777392,
    title: false
};
var vimPlayer = new Vimeo.Player('myDiv', options);
```

As expected, the video player shows up without a title:

[image: No title!]

However, upon user interaction, I want to load a different video into the same player, using the [loadVideo()](https://github.com/vimeo/player.js#loadvideoid-number-promisenumber-error) method:

```
player.loadVideo(76979871);
```

Upon doing this, the option of `title: false` gets overridden, and all subsequent loads show the title:

[image: Yes title!]

Does anybody know how to make `title: false` stick? I've also tried adding the options in attribute format on the div itself using `data-vimeo-title="false"`, as the API suggests, but once again, it only works upon first load.

I also tried passing options on `loadVideo()`, but it doesn't accept any additional parameters, besides the video ID.

Answer (score 1):

maybe create a function to do this.

```
var vimPlayer;

function loadVideo(videoId) {

    var options = {
        id: videoId,
        title: false
    };

    vimPlayer = new Vimeo.Player('myDiv', options);
}

loadVideo(59777392);
```

and from the user interaction

```
loadVideo(76979871);
```

Comment: This might work! I hope this method doesn't instantiate a whole bunch of new JS objects and make bulky network calls each time. The beauty of `player.loadVideo()` is that it only requests a JSON object, and the poster image. I'll try it out and report back.

Comment: yeah, it's not idea is it? i imagine this would re-instantiate everything every time.